# How to generate video out of images via Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, image, wordpress, video, plugins

I am working on Wordpress plugin which can generate video from sequence of images. I read here that we can use FFMpeg and Imagemagick (or imagick) to implement this trick. But, FFMpeg is hardly supported on shared hosting. So, this option is ruled out.

I started working on Imagemagick. But, I was informed [here][1] that both of the above options cannot be used for Wordpress. So, is there any feasible option for developing a video file out of images for Wordpress???

I am storing sequence of images in  /images folder and want to develop and video out of these images.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:** Here is the code I have used to test Imagemagick on my server. But, the code is neither providing the output nor displaying any error.
I am running on Hostgator and it supports Imagemagick.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: IM Trial
*/

add_action('admin_menu','admin');

function admin() {
add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Watermark', 'Watermark', 'manage_options',     'handle-uploads-admin111', adminxy );
}

function adminxy() {

$input = site_url('/wp-content/plugins/New/earth_310.png');

if($input){
echo 'Input fetched';
}
else{
echo 'Probs';
}

$output = site_url('/wp-content/plugins/New/output.png');

exec("convert $input $output");
exec("/usr/bin/convert $input $output");
}
?>
```

Please let me know if you want any further information.

Comment: Imagemagick is also not included in most shared hosting providers, but you can always make an animated gif...

Comment: Well, I am running WP on Hostgator and they're supporting Imagemagick. I want to know is it true that Imagemagick cannot be used with Wordpress??

Answer (score 0):

No, WordPress doesn’t offer any functions to create or edit videos. You’ll need external tools or libraries. Check your requirements during the [plugin activation hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).

```
register_activation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    'so9946343_check_requirements'
);

function so9946343_check_requirements()
{
    // test if it is possible to create a video on this host
    // if it fails:

    deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );
    wp_die( 'You need the following libraries and tools to run this plugin: …' );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me any library or tool which I can use with Wordpress on shared hosting to implement my work???

Comment: I just checked out "ImageMagick Engine" plugin for Wordpress which runs well on my shared hosting. The plugin is using Imagemagick php module. So, cant this be used to generate a video file? Please reply.

Comment: Can't you make your own plugin? Wordpress is just PHP, if your server lets you, you should be able to use the Imagemagick library

Comment: Exactly, WordPress doesn’t matter in this context.

Comment: @gosukiwi I am doing the same, working on WP plugin. But, the code is not working properly. Please check the question again. I have added the code. Please let me know why my code is not working.